# Checking if functions are differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, continuity

We have two functions :

$1) \;f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{xy}{x^2-y^2}&\text{when }\;|x|\neq|y|
\\0&\text{when }\;|x|=|y|
\end{cases}$

$2) \;g(x,y)=\begin{cases}
x^2\sin\frac1x+y^2&\text{when }\;(x,y)\in \{\mathbb{R} \setminus{0}\} \times  \mathbb{R}
\\y^2&\text{when }\;(x,y)\in\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}
\end{cases}$

I want to check if they are differentiable in $(0,0)$

My work so far :

$1)$ Let's take sequences :

$x_n=\frac1n,\;y_n=\frac2n$. Then $ f(x_n,y_n)=\dfrac{\frac1n\cdot \frac2n}{\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{4}{n^2}}=-\dfrac{2}{3}\nrightarrow0.$ So it's not continous at $(0,0)$ so it cannot be differentiable in that point.

$2)$ Let's take sequences :

$x_n=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}-\pi n},\;y_n=0$. Then  $$g(x_n,y_n)=(\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}-\pi n})^2 \cdot \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\pi n)=(\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}-\pi n})^2 \cdot \cos(n\pi)=(\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}-\pi n})^2 \cdot (-1)^n.$$

And the above sequence doesn't has limit to this function is not continuous at (0,0), so it cannot be continuous.

> Am I thinking correctly ?

Comment: I see now that the $g(x_n,y_n)$ has limit $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last limit, what you did is wrong. $g(x_n,y_n)$ has a limit. Because $(\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}-\pi n})^2$ converges to $0$ and $(-1)^n$ is bounded...

Comment: But the very first is okey ?

Comment: Yes the very first is good because $\mid x_n \mid \neq \mid y_n \mid \quad \forall n \in N$ and $(x_n,y_n)$  converges to $(0,0)$ and $f(x_n,y_n)$ does not converges to $0$ which implies that $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.